# How to prevent Drupal from automatically truncating blog entries?

Tags: nodes

When you enable the Drupal 7 [Blog module](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/blog), the *blog* page (http://mydrupal.tld/blog) displays truncated blog entries.  It looks like Drupal truncates after the end of the first paragraph (`<p>`).  In order to see the entire blog entry, you have to click on its title or on the *Read more* link.

I'd like to save that click to my visitors by displaying full length blog entries directly on the *blog* page.

It seems that `print render($content);` performs the truncation, but I couldn't find anything in [the method's API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/render/7) about that.

Any idea ?

Comment: Is it necessary to use the built in blog module? A View could easily accomplish what you need.

Comment: Yes I have to use this module because I'm migrating from a 6.x version with an existing database.

Comment: I strongly disagree that this is a reason enough to keep to the blog module. You should also be aware that while the module itself may live on, it has been dropped from Core in D8. I would move away from it as soon as possible. (http://drupal.org/node/233301)

Comment: Guy: I'm starting with Drupal and my management doesn't leave me enough time to get into that kind of consideration.  PLUS Drupal 7 IS SHIPPED with that module, so yeah, I'm using it, that seems pretty logical to me.

Comment: Using a blog module that ships with Drupal for blogging, yeah, that definitely is logical. I'm just saying that despite this, you shouldn't. The module is being dropped becuase it's just not a good module anymore, as is well documented in the issue I linked to. If this came across as a negative comment towards _you_, I apologize, I only meant to help. :)

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Sorry for my reaction: this whole Drupal integration is slowly driving me completely mad...  Thanks for the heads up, I'll look into it if the guys above let me ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length of the body text for a node teaser is set in the "Manage Display" section for  the content type's fields.

Just go to http://mysite.com/admin/structure/types/manage/blog/display/teaser, and change the format/format settings (i.e. "Trim length") until the teasers look exactly like you want.

[image]

Comment: I've tried it already, but nor the "Plain text" option, nor rising the "Trim length" did solve my problem.  It keeps displaying in the exact same way (only the first § gets shown).

Comment: Finally, unthicking "Teaser" in the "Custom display settings" section solved it (even if I don't really understand why).  Thanks.

Comment: I am having the same problem. After the first <p> ends the teaser doesn't display anything else, even though it is well below the trim length I set in the teaser display.

Can you explain what you mean by unthicking Teaser and where you did this? (I am assuming you mean content type->manage display->teaser, but not sure)